# Finding the next point when the angle is give

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors

I'm trying to create a code for a function which evaluates the next point when the initial point and the angle  is given...
Here, if the angle $\theta$ is give as follows (That is the angle with respect to the standard x-axis):
[image]

And if the length between $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ is known then I can use simple trigonometric relationships and evaluate the position of $(x_1,y_1)$.

But what if the angle is given along the vector as below:
[image]

Here $(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1),L_1,L_2,\theta$ are known. Then is there a method that I can use to evaluate the point $(x_2,y_2)$

Appreciate your help

Comment: According to the picture and assuming everything that is necessary, $L_1 \cos(\alpha)=x_1-x_0$ then angle between $L_2$ and $x-$ axis would be $\alpha +\theta.$

Comment: Thank you for the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the request in the previous answer, let's assume all points are in 3D, in the $z=0$ plane. Then let's use the following notations:$$\vec v_1=(x_1,y_1,0)-(x_0,y_0,0)\\\vec v_2=(x_2,y_2,0)-(x_1,y_1,0)$$
We can decompose $\vec v_2$ into two components, one along $v_1$ and one along a direction perpendicular to $\vec v_1$. To get $\theta$ to increase counterclockwise, we need this axis to point towards the upper left side in the figure. To create such a perpendicular vector, we use the cross product of a vector with $\vec v_1$. And to keep it in the horizontal plane, we need the other vector in the cross product to be perpendicular to the $z=0$ plane. So my two directions are going to be $$\hat v_{||}=\frac{\vec v_1}{|\vec v_1|}\\\hat v_\perp=\hat z\times \hat v_1$$
Here $\hat z=(0,0,1)$. Now we know that the length of $\vec v_2$ is $L_2$, so the component along $\hat v_{||}$ is $L_2\cos\theta$ and along $\hat v_\perp$ is $L\sin\theta$, so $$\vec v_2=\hat v_{||}L_2\cos\theta+\hat v_\perp L_2\sin\theta$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Draw a line through $(x_1,y_1)$, parallel to the $x$ axis. The angle between the dashed pink line and the horizontal is given by the [arctan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function.$$\alpha=\arctan2(y_1-y_0,x_1-x_0)$$
Then the angle $L_2$ makes with the horizontal is $\alpha+\theta$. The problem reduces to the case you already solved.

Comment: Thank you. It will work. And just wondering ... will there be another method that will not involve the horizontal axis? Some thing like the cross product involved

Comment: It is possible, if I assume that the points are in the 3D space, all in the $z=0$ plane. If you want, I can add a separate answer for that

Comment: Could you please do so. It will be a big help